# How do I get dbmail to process items from the queue for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

When I use the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure, I get a message saying that my mail was queued. However, it never seems to get delivered. I can see them in the queue if I run this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysmail_allitems WHERE sent_status = 'unsent'
```

This SQL returns a 1:

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
```

This stored procedure returns STARTED:

```
msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp
```

The appropriate accounts and profiles have been set up and the mail was functioning at one point. There are no errors in msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be oodles of things. For example, I've seen (yes, actually seen) this happen after:

- Domain controller reboot
- Exchange server reboot
- Router outage
- Service account changes
- SQL Server running out of disk space

So until it happens again, I wouldn't freak out over it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
sysmail_stop_sp
```

then

```
sysmail_start_sp
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is how I was able to resolve it.

Go to **Sql Agent >> Properties >> Alert System >> Check the Enable box for DBMail** and add a profile.

**Restart** Agent and it works since then.

Hope this helps,
_Ub